# Combine 3 tables and get name according to average scores

Tags: sql, inner-join, average, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have a question about sql.
I have 3 tables.

- Table 1 is student. It has student id and student name
- Table 2 is school. It has school id and school name
- Table 3 is scores. It has school id, student id and scores

I am trying to write a query where you select school name, if average of the scores for that school is above 70.

The SCORES table looks like this. I know, same student goes to 2 schools sounds stupid. Ignore that logic

SCORES

```
STUDENT_ID  SCHOOL_ID  SCORE
    1          4         90
    1          7         67
    3          5         87
    3          4         78
    5          3         56
    6          4         95
```

Comment: Homework, nice. What have you tried? Did you run into any problems? [mcve] is a great start when asking for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate and filter with a `having` clause. If you just want the `id` of the school, you can get the result you want by looking at the scores table only:

```
select school_id, avg(scores) avg_score
from scores 
group by school_id
having avg(scores) > 70
```

If you want the shool name, then use a `join`:

```
select sh.school_id, sh.school_name, avg(sc.scores) avg_score
from schools sh
inner join scores sc on sc.school_id = sh.school_id
group by sh.school_id, sh.school_name
having avg(sc.scores) > 70
```

Comment: are you shortening the table name by putting sh after school and sc after scores?

Comment: @SimpleProgramer: these are table aliases, a very useful feature of the SQL language.

Comment: I actually edited the question a little. I just need the school name

Comment: @SimpleProgramer: so just remove `sh.school_id` from the `select` clause...